# copy global memory by CUDA threads

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I need to copy one array in global memory to another array in global memory by CUDA threads (not from the host).

My code is as follows:

```
__global__ void copy_kernel(int *g_data1, int *g_data2, int n)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int start, end;
  start = some_func(idx);
  end = another_func(idx);
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
      g_data2[i] = g_data1[idx];
  }
}
```

It is very inefficient because for some idx, the [start, end] region is very large, which makes that thread issue too many copy commands. Is there any way to implement it efficiently?

Thank you,

Zheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:

```
CUresult cuMemcpyDtoD(
    CUdeviceptr dst,
    CUdeviceptr src,
    unsigned int bytes   
)
```

UPDATE:

You're right: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=88745

There is no efficient way to do this properly because the design of CUDA wants you to use only small amount of data in the kernel.

Comment: The same problem as qba's answer: this function can only be called from a host function, not from a \_\_global\_\_ function.

Comment: So, based on the nvidia forum thread, it looks like the best way is to have your thread work with the largest data type your device can natively operate with (so that each iteration results in only one copy instruction), and the optimal number of threads will have to be determined empirically because it is dependent on the memory architecture of the device.

Answer (score 1):

The way you wrote it, I am guessing each thread is trying to write the whole 'start' to 'end' chunk. Which is really *really* inefficient.

you need to do something like this.

```
___shared___ unsigned sm_start[BLOCK_SIZE];
___shared___ unsigned sm_end[BLOCK_SIZE];
sm_start[threadIdx.x] = start;
sm_end[threadIdx.y] = end;
__syncthreads();
for (int n = 0; n < blockdDim.x; n++) {
g_data2 += sm_start[n];
unsigned lim = sm_end[n] - sm_start[n];
  for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < lim; i += blockDim.x) {
      g_data2[i] = g_data1[idx];
  }
}
```